# Present Perfect vs Past Simple

Tags: tense, present-perfect, past-simple

> It has been rumored that Nicola Tesla *acquired* some knowledge from
>   this book according to James McCanney.

Why the verb *acquired* is in the Simple Past tense ?
In my thinking, the verb does not refer to a fixed date in the past and so it has to be *has acquired*.

If *acquired* is a shortened form of *has acquired*, then how could we know the rule of the shortening?

Thank you all.

Comment: Where *did you get* the idea that you have to have a "fixed date" in order to use the past simple? Does my use of *did get* have a fixed date? No.

Comment: Many text books and websites say that the past simple tense denotes  a specific time in the past and they even give the key vocabularies like yesterday, ago, and so on. Eample: http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/simplepast.html

Comment: I think I see the problem - when they say *specific* time, it doesn't mean a *known* time.  They just mean that it definitely both started and ended in the past.

Comment: A very good remark. Very helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The present perfect is not used to narrate past events. It is a **present** tense: it asserts a present state which derives from the prior eventuality. For instance, when I say *I have acquired considerable knowledge of English grammar on ELL* I am speaking about knowledge which I have now. I am characterizing the current state of my knowledge.
2. Because the present perfect is a present tense it is not ordinarily used with dead people. Nicola Tesla isn't around any more, he cannot sustain the state of  knowledge in the present, so we cannot say **Nicola Tesla has acquired knowledge.*

   (We can however say that *Nicola Tesla has died*, because the state of death is one which Tesla **can** sustain. Note, however, this will only be used when Tesla's death is "new information", a new state distinguishing the present moment from the past; usually this will be true only for a brief period after Tesla's death.)
3. There's a lot of confusion around the use of temporal expressions with the present perfect. Ignore anything you have been taught about "specific" times or "recent" times: the actual rule is that because the present perfect is a present tense it cannot be used with temporal expressions which do not include the present.
4. In any case, there is no rule which **requires** that the present perfect be used if no time is specified.

Comment: Brilliant! Then why some media state thinks like *X died* or *X has died*? Why do they include the present perfect is the person no longer exists?

Comment: @Ustanak Because the state to which the verb *die* gives rise is the state of death, which is obviously one of the few states which **can** be sustained by a dead person. I've added a little to my answer to explain this.

Answer (score 0):

Nikola Tesla died in 1943. We do not use the Present Perfect if there is no connection with the present (for example, things that happened a long time ago).
The Chinese invented printing (not have invented).
Compare:
Shakespeare wrote many plays (not has written).
My sister is a writer. She has written many books(she still writes books).

Comment: Why the downvote ? I think the answer is fine and helpful.